# Получение элемента в родителе

Tags: jquery, javascript

Здравствуйте всем. Мне нужна помощь.
Есть такой код:

```
<div><span></span><a href="">Клик</a></div>
```

Как сделать, чтобы при клике на ссылку менялось содержимое *span*, который находится в родителе?

Comment: Метод [siblings()][1] или, для вашей структуры, [prev()][2]. Это, чтоб выбрать span, ну а изменить его содержимое, надеюсь, что труда не составит?

   [1]:http://api.jquery.com/siblings/
   [2]:http://api.jquery.com/prev/

Comment: Я нуб в этом, не могли бы вы мне показать, как это сделать?

Comment: Начните отсюда -- http://learn.javascript.ru/traversing-dom

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Пример в грубой форме:

```
<div id="tadam">
<span></span>
<a href="javascript://">Клик</a>
</div>

<script>
$('#tadam a').click(function(){
$('#tadam a').prev('span').html('тест');
});
</script>
```

Для дива или для ссылки class или id установить, без разницы. Создаем обработчик события .click и выбираем элемент span, лежащий перед ссылкой, методом prev().

Comment: '#tadam a' внутри функции лучше заменить на this

Comment: Ага, так намного лучше будет.

<script>
$('#tadam a').click(function(){
$(this).prev('span').html('тест');
});
</script>